# Clustering with maximal items per cluster?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis

I have N points in a 3D space. I want to find X*Y clusters where

- N + Y <= X * Y
- Maximal Y points per cluster

Example: given 20 points and Y = 5, I need:

- 4-5 clusters
- each of the clusters not having more than 5 elements

What would be the way to solve this with scipy/numpy?

**EDIT: Explanation**

I have basically some buckets that have a maximal capacity of elements they can hold (Y). I want to maximally fill those buckets with similar elements (that are close to each other in the 3D space).

The amount of buckets (X) is limited for not having a situation where the number of buckets equals the number of elements (N) and each bucket having only one element. They need to be filled as much as possible. Hence the condition **N + Y <= X * Y** Maybe this statement is misleading. It is just to illustrate that I am trying to fill each bucket to the max.

Comment: Is it allowed to repeat some elements inside different clusters?

Comment: @SaulloCastro, no, they cannot repeat.

Comment: @aus_lacy, haven't tried anything, yet. I thought about trying to fill the buckets using the dendogramm somehow, but I am not sure what the best algorithm would be to do so.